# Alpha over not working properly for me

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm having trouble with this project I've been working on. I've been directly following this tutorial youtube.com/watch?v=9Q8PwcDzb8Y , however at 43:33 when he uses an alpha over, I'm not getting the same results. The glare works before I add alpha over, but after I add it, it disappears.

This is what mine looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/63iuf.jpg

Comment: Can you take a closeup screenshot of your node tree? That is way too small to make out.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)